# Is it possible to open Outlook Mail and import HTML text from Salesforce object field to Mail body with apex code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, salesforce, apex

I am a beginner at Salesforce field and APEX programming language.

I would like to know is it possible to open OUTLOOK and import HTML BODY text (over +20000 characters) from certain SALESFORCE object's field and import to Outlook email body using APEX code / JavaScript etc. ?